# Tensorflow Hparam replacement

Tags: tensorflow

In TF 1.12 or TF 2.0 is there going to be a replacement for the following function:

`from tensorflow.contrib.training.python.training import hparam`

I read that `contrib` module will go away or merge into core.

Comment: argparse library can handle parameters without hparam

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In TF 2.0 there is a new API `tensorboard.plugins.hparams.api` that includes a class `HParam`

Usage of the new API is described in this guide: [Hyperparameter Tuning with the HParams Dashboard](https://www.tensorflow.org/tensorboard/r2/hyperparameter_tuning_with_hparams#1_experiment_setup_and_the_hparams_experiment_summary)

Answer (score 0):

Recently found this [Weights and Biases](https://github.com/wandb/client) framework that seems to nail the job. It's a more comprehensive solution, and they've got a nicer dashboard.